# Simulate keyboard input from serial connection

Tags: android, bluetooth, serial-port, keyevent

I'm writing my first Android application and now came to the first question for which I couldn't find an answer.

I establish a Bluetooth connection with a serial communication profile. I need to receive data from this connection (it works already) and then I want to hand over the string (length between 5 to 20 characters) to a webview where it should be handled like a keyboard input (meaning the field which has focus gets filled with the data).

I tried it with KeyEvent and dispatchKeyEvent (it seems to work) but I'm not sure what is best practice for such cases. So your feedback is very much appreciated.